# BufferedReader doesn't work in arabic (encoding problem)

Tags: android, http

I want to show an arabic text in a TextView.

It work when i call it in a static form(Call the text from R.string.arabic_text), for this 
I use some methodes.
But whene i want to get the text from an InputStreamReader , it fail.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = ArabicUtilities.reshape(reader.readLine())) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        } 

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
```

The [Ulr file](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=mosque&radius=2&sll=36.859502,10.168097&sensor=true&output=json)

[pitures](http://oueslatibilel.awardspace.info/)

The text output on the emulator picture was take by an `AlertDialog` `Utils.AlertTestDeveloppementMsg(result);` and is the same on the `Toast`

I extract perfectly the field name from the file.

I tried lot of charset in `new InputStreamReader( 
                    is, "iso-8859-1")`
US-ASCII ,ISO-8859-1,UTF-8,UTF-16BE,UTF-16LE,UTF-16,Cp1256 ..

Comment: have you tried making sure that the HTTP is coming back as UTF-8 and not just an ASCII stream? That's the first thing I would check.

Comment: how can I make sure of it?, I allready exracte some information from the file, but they are in french language(work correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Http reply has a `Content-type` header, which in case of text contents contains also encoding. You are assuming that the reply is encoded in `iso-8859-1`.

So you should either manually check what encoding is used in reply or, preferably use `EntityUtils.toString()` which automatically check the encoding and converts accordingly:

```
result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: still the same result. I note some thing, the caracter displayed like &#1580; is an arabe ASCII CODE, and whene i tried to eliminate '&#' and ';' it dont work, i think that the emul show me the ASCII of that word